# What is the integration of $ \int_{γ} \bar{z} dz $ where $ γ : $ lower path of an ellipse.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, parametrization

> Problem :
>   What is the value of the integral  $$ I = \int_{\gamma} \bar{z} dz,$$ where $\gamma$ is the lower part of the ellipse
>   $$ x^{2}+9y^2=1 $$
>   running from (-1,0) until (1,0). 
>   So what I did, is a parametrization of the ellipse:
>   $$ \gamma(t) = \cos(t) + \frac{i}{3} \sin(t).$$
>   And after I did the integration like this:
>   $$ I =\int_{γ} \bar{z} dz = \int_\pi^{2\pi} \overline{\gamma(t)}\cdot\gamma'(t) dt,$$
>   and the result I got was $I = i \frac{\pi}{3}$ .

My question is, did I take the limits for the integral right? And is the method I used right?
( I changed the limits from $ [\pi,0]$ to $[\pi, 2\pi] $ thanks to ChristianBlatter at comments, so this question is answered)

Comment: I believe you made a mistake when computing $I$. I got a nonzero complex number. Could you provide us with your calculations?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter thank you, you are right.

Comment: @Gary  , yes you are right, I took the simple $ \gamma (t) $ and not the $ \overline{\gamma (t)} $ . The solution now is $ i \frac{\pi}{3} $ . The same I got before I edited my question. I'll edit it again.